# Return variable with React method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this function in JS:

```
export let findUser = (user, pass) => fetch(baseURL+'/api/Login',{
    method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username:user,
            password:pass,
        })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((res) => {
    if(res.success === true){           
            return 'A';         
    }else{      
        alert(res.message);

    }
}).
.done();
```

But when I call it in React like this :

```
var user = file.findUser(this.state.username,this.state.password);
```

I got undefined as content of variable user, How can I pass a value from the first function and get it in react native ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest exporting the initial method call and handling the `.then()` and `.done()` within the area being exported to. For example:

I have this function in JS:

```
export let findUser = (user, pass) => fetch(baseURL+'/api/Login',{
    method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username:user,
            password:pass,
        })
})
```

using in another file

```
let user // assign user within response block
file.findUser(this.state.username, this.state.password)
    .then((res) => { /* do what you want */ })
    .then((res) => { /* do what you want */ })
    .done()
```